# Convert Timezone issue in Snowflake

Tags: database

When I use the below formula

```
convert_timezone('EST', 'UTC', "Time"::timestamp_ntz) as Time_UTC
,convert_timezone('EST', "LOCAL_TIMEZONE","Time"::timestamp_ntz) as Time_LOCAL
```

for some rows data come correct and for some its's incorrect. Can anyone tell me why is it so ?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

EST is Eastern "Standard" Time and half the year Eastern time is "Daylight" time so you shouldn't use EST.  Instead you should use e.g. "America/New_York".